# Use ImageMagick to combine multiple PNGs into single PDF

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have a number of same-sized PNG files which I want to convert into a single PDF, with 3 PNG images to an A4 page (e.g. 30 images = 1 x 10 page PDF).

The images are all 1311 x 537 pixels and I'd like to stack them 3 to an A4 page. The filenames have no scheme but I don't mind the order they appear in the PDF.

Could anyone advise the best way to achieve this using ImageMagick (on Windows 10), please?

Comment: Please specify what the same size is. And your OS. Also, must they be in some specific layout or order? And are your filenames based on any scheme?

Comment: No problem, Mark; I've added the additional information to my question.

Comment: I avoid Windows as much as possible and am not sure of the terminology, but do you have the `bash` subsystem-thingy that Microsoft make available for Windows 10? And does it have the command `xargs`?

Comment: There is a Windows version of ImageMagick which I have installed and which I believe uses the same syntax as the Linux / Mac version. I see where you're going with xargs but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using ImageMagick alone?

Answer (score 11):

At its most basic, without any Powershell or BATCH commands, you can stack 3 images one above the other, without spaces and resize to an A4 page like this:

```
convert image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg -append -resize 2480x3508 page-01.png
convert image4.jpg image5.jpg image6.jpg -append -resize 2480x3508 page-02.png
...
...
```

Then combine all the pages into a PDF like this:

```
convert page-* result.pdf
```

If you have more time and patience, you can space the images out a little, or automate the process, but it may not be worth the effort.

If you want to space the images by, say 10, pixels, you can create transparent spacers in between like this:

```
convert -background none -size 10x10 image1.png xc:none image2.png xc:none image3.png -append -resize 2480x3508 page-01.png
```

---

In case any more Windows-y (**TM**) folk look at this, and feel like converting, you could do it like this on Linux/Unix:

Generate a file with all the filenames you want in the PDF, 3 to a line:

```
ls image*.jpg | xargs -n3 > files.txt
```

which gives:

```
i-1.png i-10.png i-11.png
i-12.png i-13.png i-14.png
i-15.png i-16.png i-17.png
i-18.png i-19.png i-2.png
i-20.png i-21.png i-22.png
i-23.png i-24.png i-25.png
i-26.png i-27.png i-28.png
i-29.png i-3.png i-30.png
i-4.png i-5.png i-6.png
i-7.png i-8.png i-9.png
```

I presume you would use `DIR /B | something` on Windows for that.

Then read that file, line by line and make a page of A4 sending it to `stdout` for a final `convert` to assemble into a PDF:

```
while read names ; do
   convert $names -append -resize 2470x3500 +repage miff:-
done < files.txt | convert miff:- result.pdf
```

I presume you would use `FOR /F ...` to do that on Windows, something like this mess:

```
FOR /F %%G IN (files.txt) DO (
   convert %%G -append -resize 2470x3500 +repage miff:-
) | convert miff:- result.pdf
```

Comment: That's great, I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: The image convert bit worked like a charm (all the resulting page-xx files are A4) but the conversion to PDF results in an odd page size. It doesn't retain the A4 sizes of the new source images but instead adds lots of white space to the right-hand size of the image (the pages are all 8749 x 3584 mm).

Comment: Try adding `+repage` either after each `-resize` on the original `convert` or on the final `convert` like this `convert page-* +repage result.pdf`

Comment: Right now on recent Ubuntu Linux, PDF export is disabled by default for security reasons with the following error:  convert: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408. To circumvent this, comment the line <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" /> in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml for example. Related bug https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60580

Answer (score 0):

Go to the target directory where your images are settled.

```
convert *.png  Desired_Name.pdf
# All the images will combine into the declared *.pdf file
# ImageMagick.x86_64    6.9.12.61-1.el8
```